# How can I order dictionary according to value size in python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary, example: `my_dict = {key1: [X,Y,Z], key2: [X,X,X,Y,Z], key3: [X]}` I want to create a list with the keys arranged from longest values to shortest.

For this example the list should be `ls = [key2, key1, key3]`

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: The "list.sort" method accepts a "key" argument. This key-function can provide the length for a given key.

Answer (score 0):

```
sortedList = sorted(
    list(my_dict.keys()), 
    key= lambda dictKey: len(my_dict[dictKey]), 
    reverse= True
)
```

Explanation :
The first parameter is the list to be sorted. In your case, the dict's keys.

The second parameter is the sorting key: how does it compare two elements in the list? In your case, by the len of the value of the key in the dict.
So it receives a function, that for every item in the list (a key in the dict) it returns the len of its corresponding value in the dict.

the third parameter states that the sort need to go from biggest (longest) to smallest (shortest)